# Javascript onclick function not executing

Tags: javascript, events, button, onclick, navigator

JavaScript noob here, I have a simple piece of code, but my onclick event that calls upon a function I have defined is not executing. Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>
    window.navigator
    <script>
    function thankYou(){
       alert("Thanks for Checking!");
    }
    </script>    
</title>
<style>
    td{border:1px solid gray;padding:3px 5px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    document.write("<table>");
    document.write("<tr><td>appName</td><td>"+navigator.appName+ </td></tr>");
    document.write("<tr><td>appCodeName</td><td>"+navigator.appCodeName+"</td></tr>");
    document.write("<tr><td>appVersion</td><td>"+navigator.appVersion+"</td></tr>");
    document.write("<tr><td>language</td><td>"+navigator.language+"</td></tr>");
    document.write("<tr><td>cookieEnabled</td><td>"+navigator.cookieEnabled+"</td></tr>");
    document.write("<tr><td>cpuClass</td><td>"+navigator.cpuClass+"</td></tr>");
    document.write("<tr><td>onLine</td><td>"+navigator.onLine+"</td></tr>");
    document.write("<tr><td>platform</td><td>"+navigator.platform+"</td></tr>");
    document.write("<tr><td>No of Plugins</td><td>"+navigator.plugins.length+"</td></tr>");
    document.write("</table>");
</script>
<p>
    <input type="button" name="Thanks for checking!" value="Click me!" onClick="thankYou()"/>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Why is your script tag inside of a title element?

Comment: The first thing you should do when a Javascript isn't working is open the browser's Developer Tools console. Very often you'll see an error message that helps you diagnose the problem. In this case, you have a clear syntax error, and the console will say so.

Comment: Don't use `document.write`

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo. Missing a `"` on the first document write line. Also the script tag should not be in the title tag.

```
document.write("<tr><td>appName</td><td>"+navigator.appName+ </td></tr>");
                                                            ^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

You were missing a quote and needed to move your script tag, see working example below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>
    window.navigator
  </title>
  <style>
    td {
      border: 1px solid gray;
      padding: 3px 5px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    function thankYou() {
      alert("Thanks for Checking!");
    }
  </script>
  <script>
    document.write("<table>");
    document.write("<tr><td>appName</td><td>" + navigator.appName + "</td></tr>");
    document.write("<tr><td>appCodeName</td><td>" + navigator.appCodeName + "</td></tr>");
    document.write("<tr><td>appVersion</td><td>" + navigator.appVersion + "</td></tr>");
    document.write("<tr><td>language</td><td>" + navigator.language + "</td></tr>");
    document.write("<tr><td>cookieEnabled</td><td>" + navigator.cookieEnabled + "</td></tr>");
    document.write("<tr><td>cpuClass</td><td>" + navigator.cpuClass + "</td></tr>");
    document.write("<tr><td>onLine</td><td>" + navigator.onLine + "</td></tr>");
    document.write("<tr><td>platform</td><td>" + navigator.platform + "</td></tr>");
    document.write("<tr><td>No of Plugins</td><td>" + navigator.plugins.length + "</td></tr>");
    document.write("</table>");
  </script>
  <p>
    <input type="button" name="Thanks for checking!" value="Click me!" onClick="thankYou()" />
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! Sorry, extreme javascript noob here, just started yesterday

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have a script tag in the [`<title>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-title-element). Your browser most likely will display the text verbatim in its title bar, because that's what it is supposed to do. Some browsers have (or had) problems with extra white spaces in the title, such as newlines. Better strip them.

And throw away your book, it must be really really old. Do not use [`document.write(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write), forget that this function exists. Do not use `<tag onevent="...">`, but proper [event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). Also read the console output (shift+ctrl+k or F12) to find typos in your JavaScript code.

A nice overview for primers in different programming languages: [here](http://programming-motherfucker.com/become.html#JavaScript). (The title of the site might be offensive, though. :) )